# Weird proportional font while editing a question or answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, design, editor

I'm seeing something weird this morning while editing questions (and answers). Instead of the normal monospaced font I usually see, the text is some smaller proportional font. Oddly, I'm seeing the correct font while typing this post but I've tried editing half a dozen different posts on SO and they all show the wrong font. Last night everything was fine. The font used to display the message is fine. It's only an issue inside the editing box.

And it turns out that going back and editing this post, I am now seeing the same incorrect proportional font. Very weird. Why would I see the correct font when originally posting and the wrong font when I go back and edit?

Did some CSS or something else change in the last 10 hours?

I'm using Safari 11.0.1 on macOS 10.12.6 if it matters.

Here's a screenshot from typing in a new question:

[image]

Here's a screenshot while editing this question:

[image]

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just added some screenshots. I've restarted Safari and cleared the cache with no effect.

Comment: Ah, yes, reproduced, and now I see it in Chrome too.

Comment: Same in answers, actually. New posts are fine, editing existing posts gives you a proportional font.

Comment: There's CSS that defines `textarea:not(.s-input)` to have `font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif` as part of a large number of form element selectors, all with `:not(.s-input)`. The `textarea` has a class of "wmd-input", which is defined as having a `font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif`, but that selector is less specific.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: on a new post (new question, new answer on a question page), the editor has the id `wmd-input`, so the specific `textarea#wmd-input` rule applying a monospaced font applies. When editing an existing post, the id changes to `wmd-input-<number>`, so the specific rule no longer applies.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was looking at the classes on the textarea while editing this meta post. It does indeed have an id like that, but it has `class="wmd-input processed"` on there. Don't know if that's a meta thing or what.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: it happens on both Meta and the main site.

Comment: @rmaddy Re: *Did some CSS or something else change in the last 10 hours?* If you want to see the version of the site, it's down at the bottom-right of the page, e.g. now it says " rev 2018.2.13.28925" which looks suspiciously like a date and time of some sort.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks. I don't think I've ever looked at the bottom of the page in all the years I've been on this site. Yeah, that version number sure seems like a good hint something changed quite recently.

Comment: Can reproduce in Firefox 58

Comment: I would've sworn that the editor is proportional by default (i.e. already for new posts). I distinctively remember getting nontrivial indentation right in several successive steps. So either this is nothing new or I'm getting confused between main and chat...

Comment: @AndrasDeak No, it's always been a monospaced font for new posts and editing posts. I rarely use chat so I don't know what it uses. I've been coding 38 years in fixed-width fonts. This morning's sudden use of a proportional font was like a hot poker to the eye. I can't fathom how people can code with such a font.

Comment: I think this is the first bug I've dealt with on SO. What's the process to get this resolved? Is this meta post enough?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, SO devs presumably keep an eye on posts tagged with [meta-tag:bug] and will respond or change them with the appropriate status (declined, by-design, etc.) as necessary. Search meta for the bug tag to see examples.

Comment: yes, please bring back the old font. It's a lot harder to micro-format with the newer one.

Comment: @rmaddy Coding in proportional fonts makes sense in certain languages that don't necessarily *need* vertical alignment after the first non-whitespace character, Haskell comes to mind. The official book on C++ uses a proportional typeface for C++ code samples too.

Comment: Same here on Linux Mint, Firefox 57.0.1 (64-bit).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed now, see [Font in editor for editing posts has become proportional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306954/font-in-editor-for-editing-posts-has-become-proportional) on MSE.